# Script works within IDE but does not work when run from terminal - PyQt5, Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, ubuntu-14.04, qprocess

I am having a really strange issue. My script works when I run it from within Visual Studio Code, but when I go to the terminal and type the command line below, it does not work. The code detects when a USB device is inserted. When running from the terminal, the "Device Detected" line never appears.

```
python3.6 MAINtest.py
```

When running from the terminal, something happens where either the QProcess does not run, or it never detects output from usbDetectTEST.py . Again, this code works when I run it from within Visual Studio Code. What is the difference between running it there vs from the commandline?

These are the three files that replicate the issue I am having. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

MAINtest.py

```
import sys
import time
import subprocess
from CLASSEStest import detectUSB # a file with the detectUSB class
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic


qtcreator_file  = "GUI.ui" # This can be any .ui file, it does not matter
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtcreator_file)

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.detectLogs = detectUSB()

        self.detectLogs.deviceDetected.connect(self.RefreshLogs2)
        self.detectLogs.begin()

    def RefreshLogs2(self):
        print("Device Detected")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

CLASSEStest.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
import pyudev
import time

class detectUSB(QtCore.QObject):
    deviceDetected = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self, parent)

    def begin(self):
        process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
        process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.ReadyReadReady)
        process.start("python3.6 usbDetectTEST.py")
        process.waitForStarted()

    def ReadyReadReady(self):
        time.sleep(2) # it outputs 2 things every time one USB is detected unless this is here
        self.deviceDetected.emit()
```

usbDetectTEST.py

```
# Credit: https://avilpage.com/2016/09/detecting-device-events-in-ubuntu-with-python.html

import pyudev
import sys
import time

context = pyudev.Context()
monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(context)
monitor.filter_by(subsystem='usb')

for device in iter(monitor.poll, None): # iter(monitor.poll, None)
    if device.action == 'add':
        #print(device)
        print(device.action, file = sys.stdout)
```

Update:
I added " print(QtCore.QFile.exists("/my/path/usbDetectTEST.py")) " in the class right before it starts the program, and it sent back "False". So it cannot find the usbDetectTEST.py file. Not sure why...

Comment: add `process.errorOccurred.connect(print)`

Comment: @eyllanesc I added " print(QtCore.QFile.exists("/my/path/usbDetectTEST.py")) " in the class right before it starts the program, and it sent back "False". So it cannot find the usbDetectTEST.py file. But I am not sure why... any suggestions?

Comment: use `print(device.action, file = sys.stdout, flush=True)`

Comment: Why do you use QProcess? you could use pyudev directly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54870652/notify-qml-for-usb-device-inserted-events-using-pyqt5-and-pyudev/54876584#54876584:  `self.observer = QtMonitorObserver()` `self.observer.filter_by("usb")` `self.observer.deviceAdded.connect(self.RefreshLogs2)` `self.observer.start()`

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you for your help once again. The flush=True portion solved the immediate issue. As far as just using pyudev directly, I looked at that exact post that you sent but I could not get it to work with my code. QtMonitorObserver was not working. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @eyllanesc I didn't realize QtMonitorObserver() was from the file provided in that post. Went with your suggestion, and the code is much cleaner now. Thank you again....