# Multithreaded Keyboard Detector for Linux and Windows

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-multithreading

I would like to add a keyboard detection for Linux to my existing [Keyboard Detector for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62666318/crash-after-several-seconds-of-execution-with-multithreading). So I used `pyudev` to create a `LinuxKeyboardDetector`.

The script can be started and the graphical user interface appears, but unfortunately the keyboard detection does not recognize anything and does not report any error.

I suspect that there is a problem with multithreading using `QRunnable`.

**Code**

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime
import platform

from PyQt5. QtCore import QObject, QRunnable, QThreadPool, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QHeaderView


current_platform = platform.system()
if current_platform == "Windows":
    import pythoncom
    import wmi
elif current_platform == "Linux":
    import pyudev
    from pyudev.pyqt5 import MonitorObserver


def create_keyboard_detector():
    keyboard_detector = None
    if current_platform == "Windows":
        keyboard_detector = WindowsKeyboardDetector()
    elif current_platform == "Linux":
        keyboard_detector = LinuxKeyboardDetector()
    return keyboard_detector


class KeyboardDetectorSignals(QObject):
    keyboard_changed = pyqtSignal(str)


class WindowsKeyboardDetector(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.signals = KeyboardDetectorSignals()

    def run(self):
        pythoncom.CoInitialize()
        device_connected_wql = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA \'Win32_Keyboard\'"
        device_disconnected_wql = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA \'Win32_Keyboard\'"

        c = wmi.WMI()
        connected_watcher = c.watch_for(raw_wql=device_connected_wql)
        disconnected_watcher = c.watch_for(raw_wql=device_disconnected_wql)

        while True:
            try:
                connected = connected_watcher(timeout_ms=10)
            except wmi.x_wmi_timed_out:
                pass
            else:
                if connected:
                    self.signals.keyboard_changed.emit("Keyboard connected.")

            try:
                disconnected = disconnected_watcher(timeout_ms=10)
            except wmi.x_wmi_timed_out:
                pass
            else:
                if disconnected:
                    self.signals.keyboard_changed.emit("Keyboard disconnected.")


class LinuxKeyboardDetector(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.signals = KeyboardDetectorSignals()
        self.context = pyudev.Context()
        self.monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(self.context)
        self.observer = MonitorObserver(self.monitor)

    def run(self):
        self.monitor.filter_by(subsystem="usb", device_type="usb_device")
        self.observer.deviceEvent.connect(self.process_device_event)
        self.monitor.start()

    def process_device_event(self, device):
        if device['ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD'] == '1':
            if device.action == "add":
                self.signals.keyboard_changed.emit("Keyboard connected.")
            if device.action == "remove":
                self.signals.keyboard_changed.emit("Keyboard disconnected.")


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle("Keyboard Logger")

        self.log_table = QTableWidget()
        self.log_table.setColumnCount(2)
        self.log_table.setShowGrid(True)
        self.log_table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Time", "Event"])
        self.log_table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.log_table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.log_table)
        self.show()

        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        keyboard_detector = create_keyboard_detector()
        keyboard_detector.signals.keyboard_changed.connect(self.add_row)
        self.threadpool.start(keyboard_detector)

    def add_row(self, event: str):
        now = datetime.now()
        datetime_string = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

        row_count = self.log_table.rowCount()
        self.log_table.insertRow(row_count)
        self.log_table.setItem(row_count, 0, QTableWidgetItem(datetime_string))
        self.log_table.setItem(row_count, 1, QTableWidgetItem(event))


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

**Edit 1:** Update `LinuxKeyboardDetector` class to use basic pyudev.MonitorObserver, instead of the dedicated pyqt version.

```
class LinuxKeyboardDetector(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.signals = KeyboardDetectorSignals()
        self.context = pyudev.Context()
        self.monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(self.context)
        # self.observer = MonitorObserver(self.monitor)
        self.observer = pyudev.MonitorObserver(self.monitor, self.process_device_event)

    def run(self):
        self.monitor.filter_by(subsystem="usb", device_type="usb_device")
        # self.observer.deviceEvent.connect(self.process_device_event)
        # self.monitor.start()
        self.observer.start()

    def process_device_event(self, device):
        if device['ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD'] == '1':
            if device.action == "add":
                self.signals.keyboard_changed.emit("Keyboard connected.")
            if device.action == "remove":
                self.signals.keyboard_changed.emit("Keyboard disconnected.")
```

**Result 1:** The following error message appears when a USB keyboard is plugged in or off.

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/ata/source/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyudev/monitor.py", line 532, in run
    self._callback(device)
  File "/home/ata/source/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyudev/monitor.py", line 508, in <lambda>
    callback = lambda d: event_handler(d.action, d)
TypeError: process_device_event() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: @eyllanesc I assume you mean `keyboard_detector` in the `__init__()` method of the `MainWindow` class. If so, I have to inform you that a change to `self.keyboard_detector` unfortunately did not fix the problem.

Comment: Why not use package like `pynput`. It is cross platform both async and sync keyboard and mouse monitors/controllers

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel Thank you very much for the hint. I did not know the `pynput` library yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40814233), you have to start the monitor *before* the Qt app event loop. In this case, you must *not* use a QRunnable at all, as the monitor will work as a standard QObject, working asynchronously and sending signals whenever required.

If you still want to keep the same interface, using QRunnable, I think that the only solution is to use the basic `pyudev.MonitorObserver`, instead of the dedicated pyqt version.

```
class LinuxKeyboardDetector(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.signals = KeyboardDetectorSignals()
        self.context = pyudev.Context()
        self.monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(self.context)
        self.observer = pyudev.MonitorObserver(self.monitor, self.process_device_event)

    def run(self):
        self.monitor.filter_by(subsystem="usb", device_type="usb_device")
        self.observer.start()
```

Comment: It would be great to keep the interface the same. Unfortunately, an error message appears with your suggested solution, see Result 1.

Comment: That's probably due to the argument signature, if I recall correctly, pyudev's MonitorObserver uses two arguments, with the first being the action type and the second the device. You can keep the same interface by changing to `process_device_event(self, *args):` and then get the device using `args[-1]`.

Comment: Except for checking whether the USB device is a keyboard (`KeyError: 'ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD'`), it now works, thanks!

Comment: @Atalanttore I didn't include that portion as I thought you already figured it out and you just provided minimal code. Since you're actually getting a dictionary, just ensure to go further only `if 'ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD' in device`.

Comment: Thank you for your tip, but I have already failed once in checking whether the USB device is a keyboard because `libudev` does not provide the appropriate functionality. See https://github.com/pyudev/pyudev/issues/361