# PyCharm still shows running script after it has been closed

Tags: python, qt, pycharm, pyqt5

I noticed today that a [Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62955679/multithreaded-keyboard-detector-for-linux-and-windows) running in my PyCharm 2020.2 IDE on Windows 10, when I click on the X to quit, the main window disappears but PyCharm still shows its icon for a running script. After explicitly terminating the script in PyCharm the following error message appears.

```
Process finished with exit code -1
```

When the script in my PyCarm IDE is executed on Linux (Ubuntu), PyCharm does not show an icon for a running script after clicking on the X to exit the main window.

Why is this so?

**Code**

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime
import pythoncom

import wmi

from PyQt5. QtCore import QObject, QRunnable, QThreadPool, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QHeaderView


class KeyboardDetectorSignals(QObject):
    keyboard_changed = pyqtSignal(str)


class KeyboardDetector(QRunnable):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.signals = KeyboardDetectorSignals()

    def run(self):
        pythoncom.CoInitialize()
        device_connected_wql = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA \'Win32_Keyboard\'"
        device_disconnected_wql = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA \'Win32_Keyboard\'"

        c = wmi.WMI()
        connected_watcher = c.watch_for(raw_wql=device_connected_wql)
        disconnected_watcher = c.watch_for(raw_wql=device_disconnected_wql)

        while True:
            try:
                connected = connected_watcher(timeout_ms=10)
            except wmi.x_wmi_timed_out:
                pass
            else:
                if connected:
                    self.signals.keyboard_changed.emit("Keyboard connected.")

            try:
                disconnected = disconnected_watcher(timeout_ms=10)
            except wmi.x_wmi_timed_out:
                pass
            else:
                if disconnected:
                    self.signals.keyboard_changed.emit("Keyboard disconnected.")


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle("Keyboard Logger")

        self.log_table = QTableWidget()
        self.log_table.setColumnCount(2)
        self.log_table.setShowGrid(True)
        self.log_table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Time", "Event"])
        self.log_table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.log_table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.log_table)
        self.show()

        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        keyboard_detector = KeyboardDetector()
        keyboard_detector.signals.keyboard_changed.connect(self.add_row)
        self.threadpool.start(keyboard_detector)

    def add_row(self, event: str):
        now = datetime.now()
        datetime_string = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

        row_count = self.log_table.rowCount()
        self.log_table.insertRow(row_count)
        self.log_table.setItem(row_count, 0, QTableWidgetItem(datetime_string))
        self.log_table.setItem(row_count, 1, QTableWidgetItem(event))


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What happens when you run the script from the command prompt/terminal? Is the script still running after you close the QT Window?

Comment: After closing the Qt window, the script continues running in the background. The command prompt/terminal also does not accept new commands after the window is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The friendly [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/j5q4p1/how_to_find_the_reason_for_an_error_code_1_in_a/) user [lolslim](https://www.reddit.com/user/lolslim) has finally solved this problem.

He changed the code as follows:

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime
import pythoncom

import wmi

from PyQt5. QtCore import QObject, QRunnable, QThreadPool, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QHeaderView


class KeyboardDetectorSignals(QObject):
    keyboard_changed = pyqtSignal(str)


class KeyboardDetector(QRunnable):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._stop = False
        self.signals = KeyboardDetectorSignals()


    def stop(self):
        self._stop = True


    def run(self):
        pythoncom.CoInitialize()
        device_connected_wql = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA \'Win32_Keyboard\'"
        device_disconnected_wql = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA \'Win32_Keyboard\'"

        c = wmi.WMI()
        connected_watcher = c.watch_for(raw_wql=device_connected_wql)
        disconnected_watcher = c.watch_for(raw_wql=device_disconnected_wql)

        while not self._stop:
            try:
                connected = connected_watcher(timeout_ms=10)
            except wmi.x_wmi_timed_out:
                pass
            else:
                if connected:
                    self.signals.keyboard_changed.emit("Keyboard connected.")

            try:
                disconnected = disconnected_watcher(timeout_ms=10)
            except wmi.x_wmi_timed_out:
                pass
            else:
                if disconnected:
                    self.signals.keyboard_changed.emit("Keyboard disconnected.")


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle("Keyboard Logger")

        self.log_table = QTableWidget()
        self.log_table.setColumnCount(2)
        self.log_table.setShowGrid(True)
        self.log_table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Time", "Event"])
        self.log_table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.log_table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.log_table)
        self.show()

        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        self.keyboard_detector = KeyboardDetector()
        self.keyboard_detector.signals.keyboard_changed.connect(self.add_row)
        self.threadpool.start(self.keyboard_detector)


    def add_row(self, event: str):
        now = datetime.now()
        datetime_string = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

        row_count = self.log_table.rowCount()
        self.log_table.insertRow(row_count)
        self.log_table.setItem(row_count, 0, QTableWidgetItem(datetime_string))
        self.log_table.setItem(row_count, 1, QTableWidgetItem(event))


    def closeEvent(self,event):
        self.keyboard_detector.stop()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    app.exec()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that `Process finished with exit code -1` isn't an error it just means your program was terminated.

Comment: exit code (0) means an exit without an errors or issues.

exit code (1) means there was some issue / problem which caused the program to exit.

The effect of each of these codes can vary between operating systems, but with Python should be fairly consistent.

Comment: From what I know Python give an exit code of 0 when it runs successfully otherwise it gives an exit code of 1. While other programs which give an exit code of 0 when successful or anything other than 0 if not successful

Answer (score 1):

I not sure but at the end of the code you can try write `exit(1)`

Comment: The script with `exit(1)` at the end unfortunately continues to run in the background after closing the Qt window.